# How do I upload a image to my server with meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a logo somewhere on my application page.

The application admin should be able to adjust the logo within the webapplication by simply upload a new one. What would be the best practice to achieve this?

How would I handle the upload on the server. It should replace the old logo with the new one. The name and location should stay the same.

Here is my approach:

I use the package  [UploadFS:](https://github.com/jalik/jalik-ufs:)

```
jalik:ufs
jalik:ufs-local
autopublish //it is still on, so the code below works without publish/subscribe I know that I will have to change that.
```

My code:

**Upload**

*.js Server & Client

```
//Almost Standard initialization - works so far
Logo = new Mongo.Collection('logo');

LogoStore = new UploadFS.store.Local({
    collection: Logo,
    name: 'logo',
    path: '/uploads/logo',
    mode: '0744', // directory permissions
    writeMode: '0744', // file permissions
    filter: new UploadFS.Filter({
        minSize: 1,
        maxSize: 1024 * 1000, // 1MB,
        contentTypes: ['image/*'],
        extensions: ['png']
    })
 });
```

*.html

```
//Standard initialization - works so far
<template name="upload">
    <button type="button" name="upload">Select files</button>
</template>
```

*.js Client

```
//Almost Standard initialization - works so far
Template.upload.events({
    'click button[name=upload]': function (ev) {
        var self = this;

        UploadFS.selectFiles(function (file) {
            // Prepare the file to insert in database, note that we don't provide an URL,
            // it will be set automatically by the uploader when file transfer is complete.
            var logo = {
                name: 'logo.png', //all uploaded images will have the same name
                size: file.size,
                type: file.type,
                            };

            // Create a new Uploader for this file
            var uploader = new UploadFS.Uploader({
                // This is where the uploader will save the file
                store: LogoStore,
                // Optimize speed transfer by increasing/decreasing chunk size automatically
                adaptive: true,
                // Define the upload capacity (if upload speed is 1MB/s, then it will try to maintain upload at 80%, so 800KB/s)
                // (used only if adaptive = true)
                capacity: 0.8, // 80%
                // The size of each chunk sent to the server
                chunkSize: 8 * 1024, // 8k
                // The max chunk size (used only if adaptive = true)
                maxChunkSize: 128 * 1024, // 128k
                // This tells how many tries to do if an error occurs during upload
                maxTries: 5,
                // The File/Blob object containing the data
                data: file,
                // The document to save in the collection
                file: logo,
                // The error callback
                onError: function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                },
                onAbort: function (file) {
                    console.log(file.name + ' upload has been aborted');
                },
                onComplete: function (file) {
                    console.log(file.name + ' has been uploaded');
                },
                onCreate: function (file) {
                    console.log(file.name + ' has been created with ID ' + file._id);
                },
                onProgress: function (file, progress) {
                    console.log(file.name + ' ' + (progress*100) + '% uploaded');
                },
                onStart: function (file) {
                    console.log(file.name + ' started');
                },
                onStop: function (file) {
                    console.log(file.name + ' stopped');
                }
            });

            // Starts the upload
            uploader.start();

            // Stops the upload
            uploader.stop();

            // Abort the upload
            uploader.abort();
        });
    }
});
```

**Show uploaded Logo**

*.html

```
<template name="whatever">
<img src="{{logoUrl}}" alt="Logo" >
</template>
```

*.js client only

```
Template.whatever.helpers({
    logoUrl: function(){
       return Logo.findOne().url;
    }

})
```

So If I understand it right, what the code does is uploading the img to somewhere on the server. Also it stores some info about that image in a Mongo.Collection - Logo.

But I do not exactly know where those images are stored, in which folder. They are not stored in my default Project - Folder.
The url of an example img is: http://localhost:3000/ufs/logo/B4Fv5etkr7xQbvs5v/logo.png. That random string in the middle is the _id of that img. So I can not use a hardcoded url for that images to access them, because as soon as a new img is uploaded, that url will change completely.

Q1: So the first question is: Can I upload to the myProject/public/img folder directly? So that the url of the img would be something like:
http://localhost:3000/img/logo.png
Then I would need just to replace the old logo on the upload.

For now I have to deal with the generic url. So as next, I select the url of the now present image on the server from the Logo - collection and pass that url to my template to the place where the logo has to be placed. The problem with that is, that the url is loaded after everything else was loaded, so for several seconds I get an  tag without an url in it. So that place shows the alt text only until the url is loaded. That is very ugly...

Q2: The question is, how could I get the url, before the  tag is loaded. So that the logo appears with/before everything else, as if the url would be hardcoded in advance.

Q3: Is it possible to replace the old logo with the new uploaded one, on the upload? How?

Q4: If I delete the entry for the img from the Logo - Collection, is the image actually deleted from the server? Or do I have to delete it manually/in another way?

Comment: the other question is about several images uploaded to a third party. I would like to upload one single image to my server, preferebly to the public folder.

Comment: This question is being asked in different flavors about once a week. Furthermore you are essentially just asking for code, rather than help with existing code. Questions of the form "How would I do X?" are not a good fit for Stackoverflow. The new Stackoverflow Documentation pages will be ideal for that, but are still being populated. So if none of the existing answers work for you, then show what you have tried and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the issue with my question. I have added my own approach and have explained the issues I am facing so far with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a base64 encode image on server then using fs your can overwrite the file.
Like:

**Client**

readAsDataURL has base64 encoded data in the format of

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA...

So you need to get rid of the mime type and encoding information at the front.

```
contents = contents.split(',')[1];
```

Now you can send this base64 encoded data to server.

**Server**

Since you're receiving base64 encoded data, you can convert it buffer and write to file:

```
fs.writeFile(filepath, Buffer(argument,'base64'), err => {
  //
})
```

In case the file name same as another file then it will completely overwrite your file.

Comment: Thank you, but I could not get fs.writeFile to run in my Project so I have tried my own approach with UploadFS

Comment: You have to defind fs like : var fs = require('fs')

Answer (score 0):

Answer for question 1:
default image will be stored hide folder in your project .meteor/local/build/programs/server/ufs/uploads/

You can change destination by "path" as below code

```
new UploadFS.store.Local({
  collection: Csvs.collection,
  name: 'csv',
  path: '../../../../../uploads/csv', //here change destination folder stored file
  filter: new UploadFS.Filter({
    maxSize: 1024 * 3000, // 3MB,
    contentTypes: ['text/csv']
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing the "Client" step in Pankaj Javav's answer, you may want to use the [base64-image-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-image-upload) package I whipped up, as I was having the same problem. It simplifies the process of uploading any base64 string to a server, and you do not need to get rid of the MIME type this way.